# run elasticsearch on digitalocean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, elasticsearch, digital-ocean

I'm trying to move my application from heroku to digital ocean.

One main part of my application is elastic search. It works locally by me typing in elastic search and it running on localhost:9200 This works lovely.

IT works fine on heroku. I use searchly for heroku

However i'm now moving to digital ocean. I'm running dokku on digital ocean trying to make it work, So far i've got the website on and up and running. (Yay!!)

However i'm struggling to get the search engine working. I was looking at the plugin and got really confused so any help would be great!

Thanks
Sam

Comment: Which distribution you are using,? what do you get when you type curl http://localhost:9200. For example on Centos you need to open port 9200 iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9200 -j ACCEPT..but only for localhost do not allow remote connection

Comment: @MirzaMemic I'm using hte oneclick app install for dokku, So i'm thinking its ubuntu. Not 100% sure

Comment: Can you run thisin terminal: dmesg | head -1

Comment: got this reponse `[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset`

Answer (score 1):

First check if elastic search service is running. It should be

```
sudo service elasticsearch start
```

After that you can verify if it is working

curl http://localhost:9200

You should get something like this

```
{
  "name" : "Mantis",
  "version" : {
  "number" : "2.3.3",
  ....
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

If you get curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused it could mean that service is not running or port 9200 is blocked by firewall

Home it helps

EDIT

With DO have you done this:

```
cd /var/lib/dokku/plugins
git clone https://github.com/jezdez/dokku-elasticsearch-plugin
elasticsearch
dokku plugins-install
```

EDIT 2...Configuring

```
dokku elasticsearch:create containername
dokku elasticsearch:link containername appname
```

if there is not variable set, manual config (IP is server IP)

```
dokku elasticsearch:info containername

   Host: IP
   Private ports: 9200, 9300
```

You can set ENV for your app if needed

```
dokku config:set appname ES_URL=IP:9200
```

Comment: i actually got this error: elasticsearch: unrecognized service

Comment: see my edit...I just checked it seems that this should be Ubuntu. So let see if you have it installed...try the commands that I included and let me know if it is working

Comment: you added the elasticsearch between the gitclone and the plugins install that doesnt do anything :(

Comment: first change the directory: cd /var/lib/dokku/plugins then git clone then elasticsearch..then plugins-install

Comment: didnt work for me, I'm gonna try cloud66 which seems like it might work better for me by installing everything for me :)